# Which game consoles can I target as an indie with C++ and OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, console

I am an indie game developer and I wish to build games using C++ and OpenGL for game consoles. I've read that there are strict requirements for developing games for some consoles. So does anybody know which consoles readily allow indie developers to build games for them using C++ and OpenGL?

Comment: AppleTV, Steam Machine.

Comment: I really recommend that you try using a game engine like Unreal or Unity, it'll let you focus on building the game instead of having to deal with hardware documentation.

Comment: I can certainly appreciate your desire to stick with C++ (I prefer C, personally), but if you're willing to go to C#, I believe the Mono platform + MonoGame supports quite a few platforms - PS4 is one I believe - and apparently Xamarin is working on an Xbox One port of the Mono runtime. At least you have far less to worry about and you can still use OpenGL directly if you so choose. Do be aware that if you choose Xamarin as well as MonoGame, you'll have to pay license fees @ 25USD / mo.

Answer (score 0):

When developing for consoles, I strongly recomment using an engine that already supports multiple platforms natively.

Unreal Engine supports multiple consoles, as well as Android, iOS and PC, so you are very flexible when choosing the target console, and it uses C++.

Another option would be Microsoft's XNA, which uses a C++ variant for use with the .NET runtime, but it has a limited set of supported platforms, consisting of the Microsoft platforms Windows, Xbox 360, Xbox One and Windows Phone.